# First mouse movement unexpected using SDL (C++)

Tags: c++, input, mouse, sdl

I'm working on a c++ project for school, and my implementation at this moment requires mouse input for controlling a ship (It's supposed to be a remake of Tyrian). Everything is working fine, except for the first time I move the mouse, it has an offset depending on where the mouse was when I started the game. I guess this is because I'm using `SDL_GetRelativeMouse` but how can I prevent it?

Comment: For the moment I'll just suppress the first time mouse movement is detected. This seems to work, but it seems a rather unprofessional approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the moment I'll just suppress the first time mouse movement is detected. This seems to work, but it seems a rather unprofessional approach.

Answer (score 0):

You may wish to initialize the mouse to a good known position when the application begins, possibly right before events callbacks are initialized.

Making sure the mouse is within the bounds of the window may also be appropriate.  It isn't really relevant to the application outside of its boundaries anyway.

Comment: The problem is, how would I initialize that? GetRealtiveMouse only starts working after the mouse has moved, and it is impossible to be sure this happen before the player is actually playing the game.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I do to toggle mousegrab in a FPS-type application:

```
if(event.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_z)
{
    if( mouse_grabbed ) 
    {
        SDL_WM_GrabInput(SDL_GRAB_OFF);
        SDL_WarpMouse( display->w/2, display->h/2 );
        SDL_ShowCursor(1);
    } 
    else 
    {
        SDL_ShowCursor(0);
        SDL_WM_GrabInput(SDL_GRAB_ON);
        int tx,ty;
        SDL_GetRelativeMouseState(&tx, &ty);
    }
    mouse_grabbed = !mouse_grabbed;
}
```

Consuming a mouse update via the dummy `SDL_GetRelativeMouseState()` call was the important part.

Answer (score 0):

I use this:

```
Sdl.SDL_ShowCursor(Sdl.SDL_DISABLE);
Sdl.SDL_WM_GrabInput(Sdl.SDL_GRAB_ON);
e=new Sdl.SDL_Event();
pollOne();
.
.
.
private void pollOne(){
while(Sdl.SDL_PollEvent(out e)==1){
switch(e.type){ 
case Sdl.SDL_MOUSEMOTION:
float throwAway=((float)e.motion.xrel*headSens);    
break;
}
}
}
```

Basically, when initializing the mouse (grabbing it and making it invisible) call pollOne to throw the first event away. Every event captured hereafter in the main event processing function called by the main loop is with mouse at center screen.